# How to get size of gif image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, gif, dimension

Is there any way to determine width and height of gif image with JavaScript.
I have no google result of this.
Please let me solve the problem.
It's related to this post.

[Getting Duration of Gif Image in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69564118/how-to-get-duration-of-gif-image-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 const img = new Image();
 img.onload = function() {
 alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
 }
 img.src ='your image path here';
```

Comment: thanks. It works for me.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Thanks for this valuable information @novonimo